# array that add 5 in odd and 10 in even by using afunction in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

Write a program for a function void check(int S[ ], int n) in C++, to add 5 in all the odd values and 10 in all the even values of the array S where n is the size of array.

i cant get the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use modulo % to check if a number is even or odd, if remainder is 0 from dividing 2 then it's even else its odd.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      if (S[i]%2 == 0){
         S[i]+=10;
         }
      else{
         S[i]+=5;
         }
    }
```